# React - Using componentDidUpdate to update state based on data passed from another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate, react-lifecycle

I'm learning React and working on a John Conway's Game of Life app. I have a 2D array defined in the state/the constructor which creates a game board of squares. I have a function called `isSquareAlive` that handles whether or not a particular square in the grid is "alive" in the Game of Life sense and updates squares and sets them to being alive if the user clicks on them. I also have another function called `selectBoardSize` which allows the user to click a button and adjust the size of the board.

When the App mounts I generate a random board filled with some squares set to "alive" and some not. I take care of this inside `componentDidMount`:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const data = this.state.board;
    // Creates random decimal number between 0 and 1
    const startingBoard = data.map(a => a.map(Math.random));
    // Rounds decimal numbers to either 0 or 1 so the grid can display whether the cell is alive or dead
    const rounded = startingBoard.map(a => a.map(Math.round));

    this.setState({
       board: rounded
    });
  }
```

This works fine. If the user attempts to adjust the size of the board via `selectBoardSize` I want to change the size of the board and then again fill it with random "alive" cells. Here is `selectBoardSize`:

```
  // Allows user to click button and change size of game board
  selectBoardSize = (width, height) => {
    this.setState({
      boardHeight: height,
      boardWidth: width,
      board: Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(0).map(_ =>
              Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(0))
    });
      {/*this.onChangeBoardSize(width, height);*/}
  }
```

When the user changes the board size I am attempting to use `componentDidUpdate` to grab the new board size and fill it with random "alive" cells for that board dimension, much like I do initially with `componentDidMount`. This is where I am having difficulty.

Here's my `componentDidUpdate`:

```
  // Attempts to fill board with random alive squares when user resizes the size of the board via onClick/selectBoardSize()
  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    console.log('PrevState is : ' + prevProps, prevState);

    // Attempts to update board height and width and then populate board with random "alive" squares
    if(this.state.boardWidth !== prevState.boardWidth) {
      if(this.state.boardHeight !== prevState.boardHeight) {
        // Console.log runs, if statements equate to true when user resizes board
        console.log('Nested if statements in componentDidUpdate triggered');

        const boardWidth = this.state.boardWidth;
        const boardHeight = this.state.boardHeight;
        const data = this.state.board;
        // Creates random decimal number between 0 and 1
        const startingBoard = data.map(a => a.map(Math.random));
        // Rounds decimal numbers to either 0 or 1 so the grid can display whether the cell is alive or dead
        const rounded = startingBoard.map(a => a.map(Math.round));

        this.setState({
          boardWidth: boardWidth,
          boardHeight: boardHeight,
          board: rounded
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

The board successfully changes dimensions when the user clicks the buttons to resize it, but it does not generate random "alive" squares like it should. It just changes the height and width of the board but the board is empty.

How can I use `componentDidUpdate` to fill the game board with random "alive" cells when it is resized (similar to what it does when initially mounting, but sized appropriately when the board changes sizes). Is `componentDidUpdate` the correct approach? Is this an issue with setState being asynchronous?

Pretty sure I am overthinking this.

You can check out the code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/FCC_Game_Of_Life).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `componentDidUpdate` for that, but more on that later.

This isn't working, because you (correctly, by the way) wrapped your `componentDidMount` code to into two conditionals, to check if `boardWidth` AND `boardHeight` did change. Problem is, the height never changes, so it never reaches that part of the code.

Either way, if you take a closer look to your code, you are updating the state too many times without need. If you already know beforehand which size the user wants the board to be, do it all at once.

Here's what I understand you want to do every time an user changes the size:

- Create a new board based on the desired Width and Height;
- Fill it with random alive squares;

You only need that `onChangeBoardSize` function, with a minor change.
Notice that you don't need to retrieve the board from state, because it'll be outdated with old width and height;

```
onChangeBoardSize = (width, height) => {
  // Recreate board with new width and height values
  const data = Array(height)
    .fill(0)
    .map(_ => Array(width).fill(0));
  // Creates random decimal number between 0 and 1
  const startingBoard = data.map(a => a.map(Math.random));
  // Rounds decimal numbers to either 0 or 1 so the grid can display whether the cell is alive or dead
  const rounded = startingBoard.map(a => a.map(Math.round));

  this.setState({
    boardHeight: height,
    boardWidth: width,
    board: rounded
  });
};
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/v6qlxwjwv7)

Tip: Watch out for too many sub-sequential state modifications. Always prefer to do it all at once than to trigger setState sequentially. Specially inside react lifecycle methods

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I was too fixated on componentDidUpdate and whether or not it was working. Thanks for the help.